# How to align equation number with multi-lines equation?

Tags: equations, tags

I am using long equation with 6 lines. I keep getting the equation number in the bottom of the equation and not in the middle as other equations.

I am using:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
         ........
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

I have tried `\split`, `\align*`, `\aligned`, but nothing worked. I thought the reason because the borders aren't free, but I has same behaviour when I cut the lines. Any hint?

[image: multi-lines equation]

Comment: The equation is simply too large. Look at the equation number: it ends precisely at the right margin of the text. Your equation is larger, the whole equation box sticks out of the text margin, and TeX puts the equation below it in order to keep it within the margin. You'll just have to rewrite the equation.

Comment: the last line makes it too wide to fit the number  also you probably want to use \operatorname{div}` not `div`

Comment: As already observed, the display is simply too wide.  If you can shorten the last line, perhaps by breaking it at the minus sign in the middle, you could apply `\raisetag` to move the number up to the last line.  Instructions for using this command are in the `amsmath` users guide (`texdoc amsldoc`).

Comment: Please edit your example to (a) post the entire math code and (b) state which document class and which font size you employ as well as how wide the text block is supposed to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an equation is to be labelled with an equation number, LaTeX tries to put it next to the equation. If the equation is too wide, the equation number will be put one line below the equation.

For multi-line equations, this works the same. If several lines of equations are to get one commom number, LaTeX checks the width of the full equation (!) and, if too wide, puts the equation number one line below. This is what happens in the `equation`-`aligned` combination you are using. This is also shown in the first equation of the example below: Although the length of the second line would allow for an equation number next to it, the equation number is put one line below because the full equation is too wide.

One possible way out is to not have your multi-line equation set as one equation with one common number, but instead as several equations where only one equation gets an equation number. Then, you can manually select a line of the full equation that is not too long and at the desired vertical position, and disable the equation number in all other lines. In the second equation of the example below, I use the `align` environment (which adds an equation number to each line separately) and disable the line number of the first line. Similarly, you could use this and add `\nonumber` to all lines except for a short one in the middle, to get a vertically centered equation number (although it might be very tedious to have to add `\nonumber` to a lot of lines).

Another possibility is to use the `\raisetag` macro from the `amsmath` package which allows you to manually adjust the positioning of the automatically positioned equation number. This doesn't seem to work with `equation`, so I use a combination of `gather` and `aligned` for the third equation in the example below, and raise the equation number with `\raisetag{\baselineskip}` to the level of the last line. (Actually, `\baselineskip` seems to be a bit too much, so you might have to try different lengths here to get the optimal result.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\huge
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
    \nabla a&=b\times c+d\vee e+f\odot g+h\sqcup i \\
            &=j\in k+l\div m+n\bullet o
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
\begin{align}
    \nabla a&=b\times c+d\vee e+f\odot g+h\sqcup i \nonumber\\
            &=j\in k+l\div m+n\bullet o
\end{align}
\begin{gather}\raisetag{\baselineskip}\begin{aligned}
    \nabla a&=b\times c+d\vee e+f\odot g+h\sqcup i \\
            &=j\in k+l\div m+n\bullet o
\end{aligned}\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]